# if condition in apex class to execute when we are execute test class

Tags: apex, unit-test, if

```
      Source_System_Configuaration__c systemconfig;

if(Test.isRunningTest()){
            system.debug('systemconfig'+systemconfig);

            systemconfig=[SELECT Id, System_Id__c, Source_Confidence__c FROM Source_System_Configuaration__c WHERE System_Id__c = '01siebel01'];           
            system.debug('systemconfig'+systemconfig);
            }
```

in test class my query has throwing list has no rows but i executed the same query from developer console,it not showing that exception,here System_Id__c is unique,in any circumstances it will throw only one record.can u please tel me,what might be the problem?!
thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using @SeeAllData annotation for Test Class?

Comment: no for method i had used testMethod infront of the method and @istest infront of the class\

Comment: You can add SeeAllData annotation to your test class, which will access Org Data in Test Class. The other work around is not to use SeeAllData and create your own data in Test Class.

Comment: You should really almost never use `Test.isRunningTest` checks. It should be an absolute ***last resort***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check annotation [SeeAllData](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_seealldata_using.htm)

> Annotate your test class or test method with IsTest(SeeAllData=true)
>   to open up data access to records in your organization.

So, If you give your Test Class `(@SeeAllData=True)` annotation then the test class can access Org Data.

Example with SeeAllData:

```
@isTest(SeeAllData=true)
private class TestDataAccessClass {

    // This test accesses an existing custom Setting
    static testmethod void myTestMethod1() {
        // Query an existing Custom Setting Data in the organization. 

    }
}
```

SeeAllData annotation solves your problem. But, It is best practise to create test data for your test class, instead of accessing data from Org. This will make your test class `Org Data Independent`, as test class will not be depend on Org data.

Example without SeeAllData:

```
@isTest
private class TestDataAccessClass {

    @testSetup
    static void createTestData() {
        // Create test data here
    }

    // This test accesses an existing account. 
    // It also creates and accesses a new test account.
    @isTest
    static void myTestMethod() {
        // Execute Test Code
        // Write Assert Statements
    }
}
```

Comment: @SeeAllData=True is strongly not recommended to use. Instead there is annotation @testSetup for method that creates test data

Comment: @VladyslavKushney Yes,  Thats Right. I have given both the options in my answer and mentioned that best practice is to create your own data in test class.

Answer (score 2):

Try by inserting dummy data for Source_System_Configuaration__c in test class